# How to redirect to https my domain with current htaccess settings?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm fairly new with htaccess file, and my current configuration is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, I find out that if you want to redirect to https, you need to use the following:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
 RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

My question is where exactly should I put these lines? Can I delete some from the current configuration? I would be greatfull is anyone can explain what current configuration does, or at least point to the right direction.

Comment: solved my issue by adding this code at the very top of htaccess

Answer (score 0):

solved my issue by adding this code at the very top of .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This also let's you serve static content (css, images) through https